# Infinite many roots of an equation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $k,A>0$. How may roots the equation $f(x)=\frac{1}{k} (1+\frac{A}{2}x)\sin(kx)=c,\ x\in \mathbb{R}, \ c\in \mathbb{R}$ has? I beliave the roots are infinite and one tric I thought is by using Bolzano theoreme I may find sequences $(x_n),(y_n)$ s.t $\ x_n,y_n\to \infty$ and $f(x_n)f(y_n)<0$. But I cannot compose it. Any help please?

Comment: What about choosing $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ such that $\sin(kx_n) = 1$ and $\sin(ky_n) = -1$?

Comment: Did you try plotting this equation and using positive numbers for your constants? You might get an idea of the solution.

Comment: @MartinR I did it but the  parametre c does it take any role? Those sequences are about solving the equation $f(x)=0$. If $c\neq 0$ then what?

Comment: It works with all $c$ because $f(y_n) < c < f(x_n)$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f\left(\displaystyle\frac {\dfrac {\pi} 2+2n\pi} k\right) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ and $f\left(\dfrac {\dfrac {3\pi} 2+2n\pi} k\right) \to -\infty$ as $ n \to \infty$

Hence, $f$ takes the value $c$ between $\dfrac {\dfrac {\pi} 2+2n\pi} k$ and $\dfrac {\dfrac {3\pi} 2+2n\pi} k$  for all sufficiently large values of $n$.

Comment: those are the sequence that i thought first but I thought that this argument works only when $c=0$, but no

Comment: @KonstantinosDimoglou Since continuous functions have IVP   (Internediate Value Property) the proof works for any $c$.

Comment: @Kavi Based on Konstantinos’ questioning of every answer,, perhaps he is not fully satisfied with any of his answers yet- and he has the right to not accept answers, especially if he doesn’t think they are satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

For real constants $a_1, a_2,$ The number of times $a_1x\sin(x)$ passes through any real number $c,$ which is $ \infty,$ is not affected by adding $a_2\sin(x)$ to it.

This is because the “amplitude”/oscillations* of $x\sin(x)$ increases without bound as $x \to \infty$ ( and $x \to -\infty$), so $a_1x\sin(x)$ passes through every real number an infinite number of times, whereas $a_2\sin(x)$ is bounded with amplitude $a_2$.

And replacing $x$ with $kx$ does nothing to the number of roots either, because it just scales it horizontally.

By amplitude/oscillations* I mean the distance from the "centre" of your function, which is $0$.